# 2 jquery wired problems with jquery valid and show functions

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using MVC 4 project and getting through two weird problems.

**Problem 1**: I am using a treeview

```
<ul id="red" class="treeview-grey">
<li id="adminPanel" style="display:none"><span>Admin Panel</span>
<ul>
<li><span>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Preference", "Index", "AdminPreferences")/span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><span>Platform</span>
<ul>
<li><span>@Html.ActionLink("Platform Details", "Index", "PlatformDetail")</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Now Admin Panel li is not showing be default. But when i wanted to show this panel its not working.Code i am using is

```
var adminPanel = $("#adminpanel");
    if (SiteMaster.UserIsAdmin == "True") {
        adminPanel.show();
        adminPanel.css("display", "block");
    }
```

Now it is going inside this if condition but it doesn't show.

**Second problem is with jquery valid function**.

I have html html button

```
<input type="submit" id="frmSave" name="Command" value="Save" />
```

in ready function first i am using

```
$("#formid").validationEngine();
```

to jquery validation to fire and on button click

```
$('#frmSave').click(function () {
            if ($("#formid").valid()) {
                alert('the form is valid');
            }
        });
```

but this alert is not firing up.. don't know why ?

**EDIT** : thanks to Janith Chinthana..second problem was i was using adminpanel instead of adminPanel

Answer (score 0):

put following code inside the ready function

```
if (SiteMaster.UserIsAdmin == "True") {
    $("#adminpanel").show();
}

$("#formid").validationEngine('attach',{
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if(status === true){
             alert('the form is valid');
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if its go inside if, it should work. but better you provide http://jsfiddle.net/ sample code.

Comment: it should be "adminpanel" not "adminPanel" . then it will work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35699/discussion-between-janith-chinthana-and-spenzo)